# Why, with open firewalls, would ping only work in one direction?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, routing, ping

This is what `ifconfig` reports:

```
enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:20:74:43  
          inet addr:192.168.56.201  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe20:7443/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:60 (60.0 B)  TX bytes:1650 (1.6 KB)
```

This is what `iptables -S` reports:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

`route -n` returns this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s8
```

I'm trying to ping a Windows machine with the firewall turned off. From Windows `ipconfig` looks like this:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::24ee:d94e:b400:d42c%16
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.207
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I can ping 192.168.56.201 from Windows just fine, but I can't ping 192.168.56.207 from Linux; every packet is dropped.

```
PING 192.168.56.207 (192.168.56.207) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.56.207 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 8032ms
```

I'm using VirtualBox v5 and both VMs have a `NAT` and `Host-only Adapter` network attached.

What could be wrong? Are there other things I can check? Could my host firewall be involved somehow? I'm doing this on MacOS.

**UPDATE:**
Turning on Network Discovery in Windows fixed the ping problem, but network connectivity still doesn't work.

For example, from the Windows machine I can `telnet 192.168.56.207 1234` just fine, however, from the Linux machine, I can't. My service is running on that port correctly, but I can't get my Linux machine to talk to it.

**UPDATE**
Windows has 3 firewalls that can be individually turned on and off: domain networks, public networks, and private networks. I had only turned off one of the firewalls, but it wasn't the one that matched the network type I was connected to. By turning on the firewall and setting the rule as suggested in the comments, things started working. Things also started working when I turned off all the firewalls.

Comment: Windows has a hidden setting somewhere for network discovery and ping. It's not from the firewall, it is separate. That is what is stopping you from pinging the Windows machine. It's completely normal for a Windows machine and it is a nightmare to turn it off.

Comment: Enable Firewall in Windows. Allow `192.168.56.0/24` subnet in Inbound Rules in Windows Fiewall `wf.msc`.